# Conversion of projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have received a drawing with a type of projection system which I do not recognize. [image: coordinate listing]

The drawing says that it's LO 19/WGS 84.

I would like to convert this to decimal degrees to be able to plot the drawing in Arcmap.

Comment: I might be picky, but what is your question?

Comment: Just convert from the above format to decimal degrees. I want to georefrence the drawing.

Comment: Do you have any idea about where this is supposed to be, or which coordinate systems you have to choose from? If at least the first one is true, try this service: http://projfinder.com/

Comment: LO 19/WGS 84 according to the title. It is in South Africa.

Comment: That would be useful information for you to [edit] into your question. Potential answerers do not always have time to read the comments.

Comment: Usually I use this http://twcc.fr/# to check and see where they are only if you know where they are like if you are working on your project. Or if you want to check where they are . You can use the earth icon to drag and point the place if you know where it is and then you can check it's coordinates.  I don't know if this will help you or not but just for checking reference.

Answer (score 4):

This is the Lo system used in southern Africa. You mentioned that it's Lo 19/WGS 84. I suspect it's really Hartebeesthoek94 / Lo19. Hartebeesthoek94 should be almost equivalent to WGS 84.

The EPSG code, or well-known ID (WKID), is 2048 but Esri software doesn't support that WKID because the axes order and directions are positive west, positive south and Esri currently only support positive east, positive north. We do have some "work-around" WKIDs that use a negative scale factor to "flip" the axes. The WKID for yours is 102482.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know how I can convert these figures to decimal degrees so I will be able to plot the point using the above values?

Comment: You don't need to. Once you have the values in a computer readable text file, you can use the Add XY Data in ArcMap (File, Add Data) and set the coordinate system to 102482. If you then want to get lat/lon, after setting data frame to GCS, right-click the layer and select Data, Export Data. In that dialog, select use DF coordinate system.

Comment: Others--should I incorporate my long comment into the answer?